# How to replace only missing value of specific column from datafarm 1 by value matched from data frame 2

Tags: r, join, replace, na

I have two dataframes as shown below:

```
structure(list(ID = c("a", "a", "c", "d", "a", "f"), a1 = c("2001", 
"2000", "2000", "1998", "2006", "2002"), value = c("100", NA, 
"200", NA, "400", "500")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

ID2 <- c("x","a","c","d","n","f","g","m")
a2 <- c(2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000)
value2 <- c(100, 1000, 20000, 1000, 400,500,1,1)

  ID   a1 value
1  a 2001   100
2  a 2000  <NA>
3  c 2000   200
4  d 1998  <NA>
5  a 2006   400
6  f 2002   500

  ID2   a2 value2
1   x 2000    100
2   a 2000   1000
3   c 2000  20000
4   d 2000   1000
5   n 2000    400
6   f 2000    500
7   g 2000      1
8   m 2000      1
```

**what I want to do:** I want to replace **only missing value** in column **value** of data frame 1 by corresponding value from **value2** column of dataframe 2. the year and ID should match. I tried the following code using `left_join`; however, this gave me the wrong result

```
r <- left_join(data, data2, by=c("ID"="ID2","a1"="a2"))
```

Any suggetsion?

**expected result**

```
  ID   a1 value
1  a 2001   100
2  a 2000  **1000**
3  c 2000   200
4  d 1998  <NA>
5  a 2006   400
6  f 2002   500
```

Comment: The values in data frame 2 are not uniquely identified - is this an example of your actual data?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I updated the example. My dataset was huge, so I created an example instead. Now it should be right

Comment: @RitchieSacramento with the new data, do you have any suggestions/hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `tidyverse` approach.

Note that because your `a1` and `value` from dataframe 1 is `character`, I've also changed the corresponding columns of dataframe 2 to `character`.

What you need to do is to `left_join` them together, and `coalesce` the `value` with `value2`.

```
library(tidyverse)

ID2 <- c("x","a","c","d","n","f","g","m")
a2 <- c("2000","2000","2000","2000","2000","2000","2000","2000")
value2 <- c("100", "1000", "20000", "1000", "400","500","1","1")
df2 <- data.frame(ID2, a2, value2)

left_join(df1, df2, by = c("ID" = "ID2", "a1" = "a2")) %>% 
  transmute(ID = ID, a1 = a1, value = coalesce(value, value2))

  ID   a1 value
1  a 2001   100
2  a 2000  1000
3  c 2000   200
4  d 1998  <NA>
5  a 2006   400
6  f 2002   500
```

Answer (score 1):

Using just base R.

```
merge(df1, df2, by.x=c('ID', 'a1'), by.y=c('ID2', 'a2'), all.x=TRUE) |>
  transform(value=ifelse(is.na(value), value2, value), value2=NULL)
#   ID   a1 value
# 1  a 2000  1000
# 2  a 2001   100
# 3  a 2006   400
# 4  c 2000   200
# 5  d 1998    NA
# 6  f 2002   500
```

---

*Data:*

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("a", "a", "c", "d", "a", "f"), a1 = c(2001L, 
2000L, 2000L, 1998L, 2006L, 2002L), value = c(100L, NA, 200L, 
NA, 400L, 500L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6"))
df2 <- structure(list(ID2 = c("x", "a", "c", "d", "n", "f", "g", "m"
), a2 = c(2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L
), value2 = c(100L, 1000L, 20000L, 1000L, 400L, 500L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
```